# Compare cost and value of work in EU and Europe by taxes and social security

Tags: microeconomics, taxation, european-union

In Sweden, the social security tax paid by the employer is 31,42%. Part of that goes to the pension of the individual employee. I wanted to compare the cost for the company to employ and the value for the employee in different countries. I did not find a lot of material. https://www.eurodev.com/blog/social-security-tax-rates-employers-europe For example, in Denmark it looks like significantly lower tax but in the table I found it does not give information about the total effect for the individual. Is there a more elaborate recent study, more than just comparing a single number of one tax, although that number is important it isn't the whole picture.

For example, a typical salary of 51 158 SEK in Sweden will cost the company
51 158 (in gross salary)
17 073 (= the social security tax 31,42 % paid by the employer)
2557 (= an additional 5% pension paid by the employer)

For the employer the above taxes are deductible. The corporate tax is 20,6%, so the real cost for the employer would be offset and reduced by the tax effect of 20,6 %, so
(1-0.206)×1,3142×51158+0,0×51158=**78961**

Comment: Are you looking for total tax paid by people or some sort of comparison of various taxes? For the former data exist, for the latter only selective data exist since some taxes such as social contributions are structured in heterogenous ways across europe making apples to apples comparisons difficult